# How can i keep all this html file?

Tags: javascript, html

Please i need to detect why i can not save a whole html file.

Open the next link , press CTRL+S , save in html format and then open the file that you saved , you will see that only one fragment of all the page shows up =S , i need to know why ,is some Javascript file..?

https://www.bitfinex.com/order_book/BTCUSD

I had triyed also "print it" in the explorer but it does not works.

Thanks for your help =D

Comment: Nobody should be clicking any link and visiting external sites. As for the question itself, this is off-topic, as this isn't a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

I've downloaded the page and it renders fine except for some icons and styles.

If you open your browser console on the saved page you'll be able to see the problem:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///assets/fontawesome-webfont-aa58f33f239a0fb02f5c7a6c45c043d7a9ac9a093335806694ecd6d4edc0d6a8.ttf. (Reason: CORS request not http).

Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///bfxft/static/js/10.10c7c53b.chunk.js”.
```

among other errors.

Sometimes when saving a web page not all resources are saved (like css and js files). Other static resources may be required as well and the webpage tries to get those resources from your pc instead of your server , that's when a cross-origin error occurs (trying to get static resources from a file:// url for example).

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Ok , but can you see all the orderbook..? is there information in the bottom of the page ..?

Comment: No I cannot see more info in the bottom

Comment: Ok , just for confirm(because english is not my native lenguage) , in conclusion , the orderbook is not complete , is that correct..?

Comment: Yup, the orderbook is not complete. My guess is that more elements are loaded into it when you scroll down. The elements are lodaded using ajax GET calls to the app server. Since you're saving the website on your pc , then when scrolling down, the site won't be able to perform those GET requests

Comment: Ok, but that works according what is visible in the page , i think. , Thanks for your time and help.  =D

Comment: no i did not do that im trying to fix it , but the page does not let me doit(give an up vote)